# Binding 2 images on a single tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an application where if I left click a button in a grid it changes the images to `1.jpg` and when it is right clicked it changes to `2.jpg`. I tried it several times but the image is not changing on right click.

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

WIN = Tk()
WIN.geometry("280x660+300+10")

Button_Frame = Frame(WIN,width=399,height=100)
Button_Frame.pack()
Main = Frame(WIN,width=399,height=399)
Main.pack()

img1 = Image.open("2.jpg")
img1 = img1.resize((57, 57), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)

img2 = Image.open("3.jpg")
img2 = img2.resize((57, 57), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

button_list = []
type_click = ""

for i in range(49):
   f1 = Frame(Main,width=40,height=40,bg="black")
   b = Button(f1, text = "",borderwidth=4,bg="white")
   button_list.append(b)

   def first(k):
       if type_click == "left":
           button_list[k].configure(image=photo1)
       elif type_click == "right":
           button_list[k].configure(image=photo2)

   def left(event):
       global type_click
       type_click = "left"
       print("left")
   def right(event):
       global type_click
       type_click = "right"    
       print("right")  

   b.configure(command=lambda k=i:first(k))
   b.bind("<Button-1>",left)
   b.bind("<Button-3>",right)
   f1.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
   f1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
   f1.grid_propagate(0)
   f1.grid(row = i//7, column = i%7)


  # b.bind("<Button-1>",lambda k=i:first(k))
   b.grid(sticky = "NWSE")
   
WIN.mainloop()
```

**Please tell me where am I going wrong**

Comment: Make sure to delete the old Q.

Comment: there is still a problem. the image is being added only to a single button at a time. I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to solve the problem, I made a list and appended each button to the list and then I indexed down to the current item in the list and used its methods.

```
buts = []
for i in range(49):
    f1 = Frame(Main,width=40,height=40,bg="black")
    buts.append(Button(f1,borderwidth=4,bg="white",command=lambda k=i:first(k)))
    buts[i].config(highlightbackground="black")

    f1.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    f1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    f1.grid_propagate(0)
    f1.grid(row = i//7, column = i%7)
    buts[i].grid(sticky = "NWSE")
    buts[i].bind('<Button-3>',lambda e=None, i=i:second(e,i))
```

Now you need to define two functions, one for default button press and second for left click on the button.

```
def first(k):
    global photo
    img = Image.open("img1.jpg")
    img = img.resize((19, 19), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) 
    buts[k].configure(image=photo)

def second(event,i):
    global photo1
    img = Image.open("img2.jpg")
    img = img.resize((19, 19), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) 
    buts[i].configure(image=photo1)
```

This way the code should work as indented, also instead of creating two functions you can use just one and identify the key press and work accordingly, but that will have to use event.

But here is a problem I found with the code, once you right click it, the button is not ready to be used for left click. So to get rid of that I'm using another `bind` with left click too:

```
buts[i].bind('<Button-1>',lambda e=None, i=i:first(e,i))
```

And changing the first function to:

```
def first(event,k):
    global photo
    img = Image.open("prac_img/img1.jpg")
    img = img.resize((19, 19), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) 
    buts[k].configure(image=photo)
```

Make sure to remove the `command` argument from the button.

Final code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

WIN = Tk()
WIN.geometry("280x660+300+10")

Button_Frame = Frame(WIN,width=399,height=100)
Button_Frame.pack()
Main = Frame(WIN,width=399,height=399)
Main.pack()

def first(event,k):
    global photo
    img = Image.open("img1.jpg")
    img = img.resize((19, 19), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) 
    buts[k].configure(image=photo)

def second(event,i):
    global photo1
    img = Image.open("img2.jpg")
    img = img.resize((19, 19), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) 
    buts[i].configure(image=photo1)

buts = []
for i in range(49):
    f1 = Frame(Main,width=40,height=40,bg="black")
    buts.append(Button(f1,borderwidth=4,bg="white"))
    buts[i].config(highlightbackground="black")

    f1.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    f1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    f1.grid_propagate(0)
    f1.grid(row = i//7, column = i%7)
    buts[i].grid(sticky = "NWSE")
    buts[i].bind('<Button-3>',lambda e=None, i=i:second(e,i))
    buts[i].bind('<Button-1>',lambda e=None, i=i:first(e,i))

WIN.mainloop()
```

Just incase your looking for each image to be there while you keep on clicking new blocks, then create a new list `ref` then `ref.append(photo)` and get rid of `global photo` and do the same for other function too. The goal here is just to keep a reference to the image, so its not garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You did not change the image inside the callback of `<Button-3>`.  Although you also did not change the image inside the callback of `<Button-1>`, but it did inside the callback of `command` option.

However the for loop in your code can be simplified as below:

```py
for i in range(49):
   f1 = Frame(Main, width=40, height=40, bg="black")
   f1.grid(row=i//7, column=i%7, sticky="nsew")
   f1.pack_propagate(0)

   b = Button(f1, text='', borderwidth=4, bg="white")
   b.pack(fill='both')

   def left(event):
       print("left")
       event.widget.config(image=photo1)

   def right(event):
       print("right")  
       event.widget.config(image=photo2)

   b.bind("<Button-1>", left)
   b.bind("<Button-3>", right)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to identify the `event`, `button`, and `click type` directly in the `binding`, and omit the definition of a `command` for each button.  This allows you to avoid defining functions in a for loop, and adopt an easier to understand, modify, and maintain design for your app.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

WIN = tk.Tk()
WIN.geometry("280x660+300+10")

Button_Frame = tk.Frame(WIN,width=399,height=100)
Button_Frame.pack()
Main = tk.Frame(WIN,width=399,height=399)
Main.pack()

img1 = Image.open("hex.png")
img1 = img1.resize((57, 57), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)

img2 = Image.open("pix.png")
img2 = img2.resize((57, 57), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

button_list = []

for i in range(49):
    f1 = tk.Frame(Main, width=40, height=40, bg="black")
    b = tk.Button(f1, text="", borderwidth=4, bg="white")
    button_list.append(b)
    
    b.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, k=i, s='left': first(e, k, s))
    b.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, k=i, s='right': first(e, k, s))
    # bind to <Button-2> if using an OSX trackpad
    b.pack()
    
    f1.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    f1.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    f1.grid_propagate(0)
    f1.grid(row=i//7, column=i%7)

def first(e, k, s):
    if s == "left":
        button_list[k].configure(image=photo1)
    elif s == "right":
        button_list[k].configure(image=photo2)


b.grid(sticky="NWSE")
   
WIN.mainloop()
```

**Note:**
You will need to adjust the resizing of the buttons as an image is inserted; I did not have your images, so I left it at that.